# Can someone help me i get an Attribute Error in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
import django 
import sys
django.setup() 
import os
```

I think what I've imported is good, i think maybe it comes from my `urls.py` but I don't know what to add to it

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'm0i@n*1e&b6@5w7^#=h712+z#-jj2&ynbi30j0z$yf#t+@x1s#'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.101', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
```

I allowed hosts to try debbugging

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite',
    'polls' ]
```

Installed apps of Django

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', ]
```

Middleware of Django

My error come from here

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }, ]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    } }



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    }, ]
```

Settings of Django:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Backend authentification:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth',)
```

I can't understand why I get an **Attribute Error** in my console when I launch the server !

Comment: *an Attribute Error in Django* is not enough information. Please show the command you are running and the full error message. Where do the first four lines of code in your question come from?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't post `SECRET_KEY` online. Please make sure you change it before you ever deploy your site online.

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 15, 2019 - 17:08:17
Django version 2.1.7, using settings None
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/File "C:\Users\ifocop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\ifocop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

Comment: Don't post code or errors in the comments - [edit] your question.

Comment: What is `apps.apployment_site.auth.CustomAuth` and why are you using it?

Comment: why is `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: My site is local it’s not online

Comment: 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' I’ll try with it

Comment: Further formatting, remove extra newlines.